# Matplotlib/tkinter: Event picking on the legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am having trouble amending this code, so it is can pick a line in tkinter by clicking the legend. I wanted to amend the code from this [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html)

This is the code I have come up with so far. It just plots the line in tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        plotFrame = tk.Frame(master)
        plotFrame.pack()

        f = Figure(figsize=(5,4),dpi=100)
        self.ax = f.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master=plotFrame)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

        line1, = self.ax.plot(t, y1, lw=2, color='red', label='1 HZ')
        line2, = self.ax.plot(t, y2, lw=2, color='blue', label='2 HZ')
        leg = self.ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
        leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)

    def onpick(event):
        # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
        # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibility
        legline = event.artist
        origline = lined[legline]
        vis = not origline.get_visible()
        origline.set_visible(vis)
        # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
        # have been toggled
        if vis:
            legline.set_alpha(1.0)
        else:
            legline.set_alpha(0.2)
        fig.canvas.draw()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

    plt.show()



root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem. In the example you link to there is a function `on_pick` and a `'pick_event'` beeing registered to it. Since those parts are completely missing from your code, it will of course not show the desired effect. You need to include them and if you then have a problem, show the code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: I have edited the code to show what I would have done. If the code is run from python the lines can be toggled on and off. If I run this, the lines cannot be toggled on or off in a tkinter window.

Comment: Mind your indentation. Also there are >5 undefined variables. After posting a code in a question, verify that it can be copied and run to reproduce the (un)desired behaviour you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write your [tkinter GUI in an object-oriented style](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/213943), you need to make better use of the object-oriented structure. In particular:

**1-** Keep your code within the class's methods:

```
# In your example, the following lines are outside any method
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

**2-** Use the `self` variable to store objects that you want to access in different methods:

```
# Add self as the first argument in onpick()
def onpick(self, event):
    (...)
    # Now you can access self.canvas defined in __init__()
    self.canvas.draw()
```

See below a working version of your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 0.2, 0.1)
y1 = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
y2 = 4*np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t)

class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        plotFrame = tk.Frame(master)
        plotFrame.pack()

        f = Figure(figsize=(5,4),dpi=100)
        self.ax = f.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=plotFrame)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)

        line1, = self.ax.plot(t, y1, lw=2, color='red', label='1 HZ')
        line2, = self.ax.plot(t, y2, lw=2, color='blue', label='2 HZ')
        leg = self.ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
        leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)

        # we will set up a dict mapping legend line to orig line, and enable
        # picking on the legend line
        lines = [line1, line2]
        self.lined = dict()
        for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
            legline.set_picker(5)  # 5 pts tolerance
            self.lined[legline] = origline

    def onpick(self, event):
        # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
        # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibility
        legline = event.artist
        origline = self.lined[legline]
        vis = not origline.get_visible()
        origline.set_visible(vis)
        # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
        # have been toggled
        if vis:
            legline.set_alpha(1.0)
        else:
            legline.set_alpha(0.2)
        self.canvas.draw()


root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Josselin! Really appreciate the advice