# Matplotlib/tkinter: Event picking on legend when opening multiple windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

This is a follow up to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727512/matplotlib-tkinter-event-picking-on-the-legend/46756564#46756564) on Matplotlib functionality in tkinter. I am trying to develop a program that opens multiple windows containing plots when I train a model. The values are stored in aveCR as a dictionary with each key storing multiple arrays. For each key, I am plotting the arrays in a new window and therefore using a for loop to open a new window (not sure if this is good practice!)

The problem I have is with the legend for each window. The ability to toggle lines on/off is only available on the final window and I would like to have this functionality available on every new window opened. I know that `self.lined` is overwritten with the final plot from the for loop, but I am not sure if I should add this to the for loop.

I have added dummy figures below for aveCR, so the code can be run. Any advice in approaching this would be appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        # Frame for the training values
        buttonFrame = tk.Frame(master)
        buttonFrame.pack()

        self.buttonGenerate = tk.Button(master=buttonFrame,
                                        text='Train',
                                        command=self.train)
        self.buttonGenerate.grid(column=2,row=0)


    def train(self):

        aveCR = {0:{0:np.array([.582,1.081,1.507,1.872,2.180]),1:np.array([2.876,6.731,1.132,1.305,1.217])},
            1:{0:np.array([.582,1.081,1.507,1.872,2.180]),1:np.array([2.876,6.731,1.132,1.305,1.217])}}

        legend = {0: ['A', 'AB'], 1: ['A', 'AB']}

        for i in range(len(aveCR)):
            t = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
            # Frame for the plot
            plotFrame = tk.Frame(t)
            plotFrame.pack()

            f = plt.Figure()
            self.ax = f.add_subplot(111)
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master=plotFrame)
            self.canvas.show()
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
            self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)

            # Plot
            lines = [0] * len(aveCR[i])
            for j in range(len(aveCR[i])):        
                X = range(0,len(aveCR[i][j]))
                lines[j], = self.ax.plot(X,aveCR[i][j],label=legend[i][j])
            leg = self.ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=2, borderaxespad=0.)

        self.lined = dict()
        for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
            legline.set_picker(5)  # 5 pts tolerance
            self.lined[legline] = origline


    def onpick(self, event):
        # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
        # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibility
        legline = event.artist
        origline = self.lined[legline]
        vis = not origline.get_visible()
        origline.set_visible(vis)
        # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
        # have been toggled
        if vis:
            legline.set_alpha(1.0)
        else:
            legline.set_alpha(0.2)
        self.canvas.draw()



root = tk.Tk()
root.title("hem")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably mostly a design problem. I would recommend using a class for each plot window. The `App` class can then instantiate as many of those plot windows as you need, supplying the respective data as arguments. Each plot window manages the legend and events for itself.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

import Tkinter as tk

class Plotwindow():
    def __init__(self, master, data, legend):
        t = tk.Toplevel(master)
        # Frame for the plot
        plotFrame = tk.Frame(t)
        plotFrame.pack()

        f = plt.Figure()
        self.ax = f.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master=plotFrame)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)

        # Plot
        lines = [0] * len(data)
        for j in range(len(data)):        
            X = range(0,len(data[j]))
            lines[j], = self.ax.plot(X,data[j],label=legend[j])
        leg = self.ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=2, borderaxespad=0.)
        self.lined = dict()
        for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
            legline.set_picker(5)  # 5 pts tolerance
            self.lined[legline] = origline

    def onpick(self, event):
        # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
        # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibility
        legline = event.artist
        origline = self.lined[legline]
        vis = not origline.get_visible()
        origline.set_visible(vis)
        # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
        # have been toggled
        if vis:
            legline.set_alpha(1.0)
        else:
            legline.set_alpha(0.2)
        self.canvas.draw()

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        # Frame for the training values
        buttonFrame = tk.Frame(master)
        buttonFrame.pack()

        self.buttonGenerate = tk.Button(master=buttonFrame,
                                        text='Train',
                                        command=self.train)
        self.buttonGenerate.grid(column=2,row=0)

    def train(self):

        aveCR = {0:{0:np.array([.582,1.081,1.507,1.872,2.180]),1:np.array([2.876,6.731,1.132,1.305,1.217])},
            1:{0:np.array([.582,1.081,1.507,1.872,2.180]),1:np.array([2.876,6.731,1.132,1.305,1.217])}}

        legend = {0: ['A', 'AB'], 1: ['A', 'AB']}

        self.windows = []
        for i in range(len(aveCR)):
            data = aveCR[i]
            self.windows.append(Plotwindow(self.master,data, legend[i]))


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("hem")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!